# How am I getting more 503s than requests with my AWS Application Load Balancer?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-application-load-balancer

I have an Application-type load balancer with AWS that serves 3 node apps. On weekends, very few requests come in. I noticed today through cloudwatch that more 503s are reported in the metrics than actual requests. Sporadically I'll get 1 or 2 here and there, but on occasion I get big spikes. The latest one had hundreds of 503 responses in a 10-15 min window, but only 2 requests... I think it could be a health checks failing but then I can't find any logs indicating failing health checks. We're not deploying anything at these times. No errors in our app logs. No errors in the app nginx log groups. I'm not a IT/Devops guy and I'm not sure where else to look. Where could these be coming from?

Edit: here is a look at what I am seeing
[image]

As you can see, the high points in requests and 503s are not happening at the same time so there doesn't seem to be a correlation between requests and 503s.

Comment: Do you have multiple targers in your load balancer? maybe the requests aren't going to your app because it's not matching the path / host name .

Comment: Yes, we are serving a few different apps behind the same balancer. How would I see logs of unmatched requests?

Comment: I'm fairly certain there are logging options for API gateway, and I think they are off by default. Google is your friend

Comment: Thanks, that pointed me in the right direction, It turns out I had turned on logging a long time ago and forgot about it or where to find it. The logs show a big series of calls by ip address. Things like "GET http://44.444.444.444:80/a.gz" where they search for files names with simple letters and numbers. I'm guessing that is someone scanning our server for unprotected files with simple/common names.

Comment: Possible! people scan for vulnerabilities all the time. That ip address longs wrong (can't go higher than 254 for each segment) so i assume it's anonymized. Sometimes you can google the specific requests they are making to find out what vuln they are trying to exploit.

Comment: Your first comment pretty much hit the nail on the head. I've adjusted my alarms to effectively ignore 503s coming from only the load balancer. If you post that as the answer, I'll mark it for you. Otherwise I'll post the answer after some time.

Comment: I'm too lazy to turn it into a full-blown answer, but I'm glad I could help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Evert said in the comments, these 503s were coming from requests that did not match any rules for a valid target group. My default target group does not actually forward to anything and so they were not counted as requests.

I was able to find the access logs for the load balancer and found it was being scanned for vulnerabilities by potentially malicious users. They used the IP address of the server, which I don't have rules for, and looked for common files found on various platforms that might not have been secured properly. This would cause a spike in 503s.

Instead of one generic alarm for 5XXs from the load balancer, I set my alarms to listen for issues from the actual requests to the apps. Metrics with ELB in them seem to be load balancer metrics, and similarly named metrics without ELB in the name measure what comes from the apps.